# use jni for two instance of a class

Tags: java, synchronization, java-native-interface

I have a java class and this class connects to target system over the `jni`. Library loaded with System.load(...) . Everything works fine when I use one instance and one target.  But  I try to use two instances of class which instances will connect to two different target. For example; `InstanceA connects to TargetA` and `InstanceB connects to TargetB`. But  when InstanceB connects to TargetB, it overwrites the InstanceA 's variables `as expected`.

I think I can use threads in jni but there are callback methods which are called by target and there is no specific value in callback methods parameters to determine which threads worked.

How can I handle this issue? Any idea for that?

Comment: I am confused regarding to your "it overwrites the InstanceA 's variables as expected". Post the code of your class InstanceA/InstanceB so that we can have a look. Could you clarify what you meant with your JNI Threads? Are you talking about Java Threads? or Threads inside your JNI code?

Comment: sorry @GuillaumePolet. You right. It is a wrong sentence. I just realize that. When I reviewed the question, I changed some sentences and forgot to change this. I can just take a look at the my question now and see the weird sentence. what a shame.... I solved the issue and will share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you have Java or native data that is static that shouldn't be static.

Comment: You right. My fault. I must posted the code here. So, there was no any static variable/method. Just colleagues missed to set the pointer of structure.